# On unity i got a error with the camera if you know how to fix it please tell me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the picture of what i  mean
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkKK8.png)

[Here is the list of components it has with the code i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AM27.png)

here is the code for the ones that wanted:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

  public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
  {

    public AudioSource Scream;
    public GameObject ThePlayer;
     public GameObject JumpCam;

     void OnTriggerEnter () {
      Scream.Play ();
      JumpCam.SetActive (true);
     ThePlayer.SetActive (false);
      StartCoroutine (EndJump ());

 }


        IEnumerator EndJump() {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds (6.06f);
        ThePlayer.SetActive (true);
        JumpCam.SetActive (false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code inside of your JumpTrigger-Script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just did i put out the code i hope you can find the problem and tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Camera object has been disabled in the hierarchy. Click it and enable its checkbox in the inspector window.

Comment: The thing is i have a code for it to enable again so it has to be turned off possible is something wrong with my code?

Comment: The error means no camera is enabled, so maybe your code is not enabling it on startup.

Comment: oh ok ill have a look on it later thanks!